# How can one go from a jquery collection to the actual jquery ($) object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an existing jquery collection, generated like this:

```
obj = $('some-selector')
```

obj is passed to a method that uses $('some-other-selector').data('some-data-attribute');

However, the value of $ may have been redefined by the time this method is called (say, because of different jquery versions on the page).

Therefore, I need to get hold of the $ object that was used to generate the original obj.
Is there some way I can go from obj to the $ object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant.. but in case you need to get the jQuery element from a regular HTMLElement you could use `$(object)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just store the original jQuery object in a variable to use it later or whenever you need to? Anyway, for this kind of scenarios, you should rather use the specific jQuery tool, noconflict.

See: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page#answer-1566644)

Comment: yes, i can but I have a lot of these functions, and don't want to pass $ to each of them. I am already passing obj though.